# Query geospatial data with BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I would like to obtain a list of public locations (restaurant, hotels, cinema etc.) neighbours based on GPS coordinates. Is this possible with BigQuery ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have lat-lon or GPS coordinates as columns, you could definitely grab rectangular regions from BigQuery using WHERE comparisons on the coordinates and then aggregate on the selected rows.

The scalar operations available in BigQuery are pretty powerful too -- you can add a variety of [arithmetic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#mathfunctions) to your query and still get excellent performance.

You find listed example queries on the linked page:

- Return a collection of points within a rectangular bounding box centered around San Francisco (37.46, -122.50).
- Return a collection of up to 100 points within an approximated circle determined by the using the Spherical Law of Cosines, centered around Denver Colorado (39.73, -104.98).

Answer (score 3):

GCP announced new geospatial data types and functions with BigQuery GIS.New functions and data types follow the SQL/MM Spatial standard and will be familiar to PostGIS users and anyone already doing geospatial analysis in SQL.
Also, a new lightweight visualization tool called BigQuery Geo Viz is announced which is designed for BigQuery users that want to plot and style their geospatial query results on a map.

Implementation, currently in alpha. You can request to get access.
More details can be found here - [GCP Blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2018/07/bridging-the-gap-between-data-and-insights)